# Conditional shapefile merge using ArcGIS Pro ModelBuilder

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, modelbuilder

I have a basic model in which I want to buffer a shapefile. I've got some spatial data that will always be included, but I'd like to have the option for the user to set a secondary shapefile as a parameter which, if it's set, the model merges with the other before buffering.

I thought that this would be simple with the "If data exists" tool like this:

[image]

This will work with the "optional shapefile" parameter blank if I try to run the model through the editor, but I've found that it won't if I try to run it through the geoproccessing window, when I click run model I get the message "Parameter is missing or invalid".

Comment: I created the first part of your model (if and merge), and I CAN run the model with a blank "optional shapefile". Nothing happens, but that is expected. Can you describe how you can't run the model with the parameter blank?

Comment: @KHibma I can also run the model in edit view while leaving the optional shapefile blank, but if I try to run the model through the Geoprocessing window when I click the button to run the model I get the error "Parameter is missing or invalid".

Comment: That works for me. In the Catalog pane, can you right click your model, select properties and verify your input is set to optional (vs being required)?

Comment: I just checked and it is still optional for me, but I still get the "parameter is missing or invalid message". Also, next to the space in input the file path for the additional shapefile I have a red "X" with the error "000468 Input Shape types are not equal" but I assume that is just because it is blank at the moment.